# Retrieving file type for /drive child listing

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

For the v1.0 Graph API endpoint `/drive/root/children` is it possible to return the type of each file? i.e., microsoft word file vs excel vs onenote (etc)?

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_list_children):

> Here is an example of the response.
>
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-type: application/json
>
> ```
> {   "value": [
>         {"name": "myfile.jpg", "size": 2048, "file": {} },
>         {"name": "Documents", "folder": { "childCount": 4} },
>         {"name": "Photos", "folder": { "childCount": 203} },
>         {"name": "my sheet(1).xlsx", "size": 197 }   ],
>    "@odata.nextLink": "https://..." 
> }
> ```

Microsoft uses the file extension to identify folders. Matching the file extension should be good enough. One caveat: files may have no extension or the wrong one. In this case it is necessary to read the file for its file type. Bitmap files famously start with `BM`, and Executables `MZ` for example. There may be other ways of recognizing file types. Since Office moved to XML-based files, you might be able to tell from the XML Schema or doctype.

Folders can be identified by the folder labeled nested JSON object. There are additional details that aren't useful to you.

The "@odata.nextLink" field enables pagination. Going to that url shows more files without draining resources.

Answer (score 0):

The OneDrive API supports the following file type recognition today, through the use of properties on an item:

- File
- Folder
- Photo (taken with a camera)
- Image (bitmap)
- Audio
- Video

These are all determined by seeing if the corresponding property on the item is null or not-null. We call this data model a "facet" approach, since the item contains multiple facets which represent ways you can treat the item.

If you care about more granularity than that, you can check for the file property being not-null and then examine the file extension to determine file type.

OneDrive Personal also includes a guess at the MIME type of the file in the item.file.mimeType property. This can use used in some scenarios to better understand file type without parsing extensions.